# Extract last part of url without query string or jsessionid

Tags: regex, url, jsessionid

I want a regex that will always return the last part of an url before the query string parameters and without the jessionid if present.

Here's some url examples:

```
http://www.somesite.com/some/path/test.action;jsessionid=000063vCmvJAn7VWyymA_dPsHZs:16u9pglit?sort=2&param1=1&param2=2
http://www.somesite.com/some/path/test;jsessionid=000063vCmvJAn7VWyymA_dPsHZs:16u9pglit?sort=2&param1=1&param2=2
http://www.somesite.com/some/path/test.action?sort=2&param1=1&param2=2
http://www.somesite.com/some/path/test?sort=2&param1=1&param2=2
```

Here's my regex so far:

```
.*http://.*/some/path.*/(.*);?.*\?.*
```

It is working for the url that does not contain jsessionid, but will return `test;jessionid=...` if it is present.

To test: http://regex101.com/r/fM0mE2

Comment: Like http://regex101.com/r/dT4uL5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/wU0jA2/5):

```
.*http:\/\/.*\/some\/path.*\/([^;\?]+);?.*\?.*
                              ^^^^^^
```

Basically matches anything that isn't `;` or `?`. And I think it might be shortened to:

```
.*http:\/\/.*\/some\/path.*\/([^;\?]+)
```

Comment: What about a url like abc.com?var=val1/dfg. If it goes till the last forward slash then it gives the wrong result.

Comment: @Sohaib I'm not sure what you mean? Also that answer was from nearly 3 years ago now, probably can be improved at this point. Plus it looks like the link there is broken now =/